# Subscript out of range error pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one worksheet to another.

Whenever it counts the cells and comes to the point of pasting the data, it gives me an out of range error.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim nmrow As Long, avrow As Long
    
'check  last filled line in database
nmrow = Worksheets("SYSTEMDATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
For i = 2 To nmrow
    'check last filled line in mark sheet
    avrow = Worksheets("MKSHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Worksheets("SYSTEMDATA").Cells(i, 7).Copy
      'pasting data into mark sheet(names)
    Worksheets("SYSTEMDATA").Paste Destination:=Worksheets(MKSHEET).Cells(avrow + 1, 2)
    
    'copying and pasting english into mksheet
    Worksheets("SYSTEMDATA").Cells(i, 13).Copy
    Worksheets("SYSTEMDATA").Paste Destination:=Worksheets(MKSHEET).Cells(avrow + 1, 3)
    
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the quote marks around the worksheet MKSHEET in both commands for the destination parameter.

Errors like that can easily be avoided if you use `Option Explicit` above your code, so you cannot use variables without declaring them first. Using `MKSHEET` like this would result in the warning that a variable is not defined, and your code wouldn't even compile.